# How to test if <label> is not rendered in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tdd, react-testing-library

I am trying to test if the  component was rendered or not in my code depending on whether it was provided to the wrapping component or not. I am facing the issue of not being able to check if it or not because I can't think of a way to find it on the screen.

```
  return (
    <>
      <If condition={label?.length > 0}>
        <label htmlFor={name}>
          {label}
        </label>
      </If>

      <Field type="text" id={name} name={name} placeholder={placeholder} />
      <ErrorMessage name={name} component="small" />
    </>
  );
```

One (hack-ey) way of doing it was to provide the `<label>` with "aria-label" (`<label aria-label="customLabel"/>`), then using `screen.findByLabelText("customLabel").not.toBeInTheDocument()`

What can I use to find it without directly accessing the DOM elements?

Comment: Since the `<label>` presence depends on the `label` value I can't think of a better way to do the check. However, you could use `data-testid` instead of the `aria-label` attribute in this case, to avoid adding extra unneeded `aria-*` attributes.

Answer (score -2):

In your case you need 2 things:

1. await findBy* method to test that your element is rendered, and
2. queryBy* method to test that your element is not rendered.

When your element is conditionally rendered you need to use findBy*, and you need to use await along with it (`expect(await findBy*(...)).toBeInTheDocument();`).

Also, you need to mock your parent/wrapping component, and depending on that to make assertation.

From the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries):

> getBy...: Returns the matching node for a query, and throw a
> descriptive error if no elements match or if more than one match is
> found (use getAllBy instead if more than one element is expected).

> queryBy...: Returns the first matching node for a query, and return
> null if no elements match. This is useful for asserting an element
> that is not present. Throws an error if more than one match is found
> (use queryAllBy instead if this is OK).

> findBy...: Returns a Promise
> which resolves when an element is found which matches the given query.
> The promise is rejected if no element is found or if more than one
> element is found after a default timeout of 1000ms. If you need to
> find more than one element, use findAllBy.